# Radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^kk}{k^k}x^k$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

The question considers the power series  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^kk}{k^k}x^k$.

The question is to show that the radius of convergence is $(-\infty,\infty)$, but without using the nth root test of convergence.
[I can do the question using the nth root test with no issue.]

In lectures we have only used the usual radius of convergence formula
$R=\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}$ derived from the ratio test.

But this yields an impossible expression!

I get

$R=\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln^kk}{k^k}\cdot \frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{\ln^{k+1}(k+1)}$

$\therefore R>\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln^kk}{k^k}\cdot \frac{k^{k+1}}{\ln^{k+1}(k+1)}$

$\therefore R>\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{k\ln^kk}{\ln^{k+1}(k+1)}$

I need to show this diverges. Of course $k> \ln k$ but I can't see how to proceed here.

L'Hopital's Rule applies but the derivatives are awful!

Wolfram Alpha says it diverges!

Any hints on what I am missing and how to proceed please. Thanks :-)

Comment: Quick LaTeX note: Consider using \cdot « $\cdot$ » instead of \times « $\times$ » as it is often less confusing. And for a hint: Try separating $\log(k+1)^{k+1}= \log(k+1)\cdot \log(k+1)^k$ and then look at the ratios of the differents terms. Is there some that tends to infinity or to 1 maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{k\ln^kk}{\ln^{k+1}(k+1)} 
=\frac k{\ln(k+1)}\cdot\left(\frac {\ln k}{\ln(k+1)}\right)^k
=\frac k{\ln(k+1)}\cdot\left(1-\frac {\ln(1+\frac 1k)}{\ln (k+1)}\right)^k
$$
and by Bernnoulli together with $\ln(1+x)\le x$,
$$\left(1-\frac {\ln(1+\frac1 k)}{\ln (k+1)}\right)^k\ge 1-  \frac {k\ln(1+\frac 1k)}{\ln (k+1)}\ge 1-\frac{1}{\ln(k+1)}.$$

Comment: Thankyou so much. So the final argument is $R>\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} {k\over \ln(k+1)}\cdot \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}  \left(1 -{ 1\over \ln(k+1)} \right) = \infty\cdot 1 =\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for any fixed $x$,
$$
\frac{{\ln k}}{k}\left| x \right| = \frac{{2\ln \sqrt k }}{k}\left| x \right| \le \frac{{2\sqrt k }}{k}\left| x \right| = \frac{2}{{\sqrt k }}\left| x \right| \to 0
$$
as $k\to +\infty$.